# how to concatenate two or more string stored in a variable inside awk script

Tags: linux, unix, awk, ksh

i want to concatenate three variable output to one variable inside a awk script in print statement.
ex:
`a="a"`
`b="b"`
`c="c"`
and expected output is
 `d=a-b-c`

Comment: are `a`, `b`, and `c` shell or awk variables? Do you want to print `d=a-b-c` or do you want to create a variable `d` populated with the string `a-b-c`? Is `d` a shell variable or an awk variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say if the three variables are awk variables or shell variables so assuming they are awk variables:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"
    print "d=" a "-" b "-" c
}'
d=a-b-c
```

If they are shell variables, see @Jotne's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it:

```
a=a
b=b
c=c
d=$(awk -v x="$a" -v y="$b" -v z="$c" -v OFS="-" 'BEGIN {print x,y,z}')
echo $d
a-b-c
```

You declare variable  in `awk`, by using the `-v` option.

---

Or to print it, if that is what you need

```
awk -v x="$a" -v y="$b" -v z="$c" -v OFS="-" 'BEGIN {print "d="x,y,z}'
d=a-b-c
```

Comment: @EdMorton It was more for the other post above me, that was posted by other.  Fixed text.

Comment: Ah, got it. You should change `You declare variable in awk, by using the -v option` to `You can initialize variables in awk by using the -v option` since you still never declare variables in awk. Declaring would be statements like `int c;` (C syntax) to provide a type for a variable while initing is setting an initial value like `c = 3`.